# Regular expression to disallow backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I disallow the backslash using regular expression in javascript.
I tried as `[^\\]` but it didn't work out.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: where what? what is your code?

Comment: What do you mean by disallow backslash? Post some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: Add sample input string and expected output string.

Comment: If you simply want to get rid of it, why not use `replace`?  Or do you want to get rid of all strings starting with or containing a backslash?

Answer (score 1):

#### Regular expression

```
 ^[^\\]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Sample code

```js
var input= [
   '\\',
   'foo',
   'bar\\baz'
 ];

var re = /^[^\\]+$/;

var len=input.length;
var output = [];
for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
    output.push(input[i] + ' [' + re.test(input[i]) + ']');
}

document.write('<pre>' + output.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /[^\\]/g;
```

This should do it for you.Use `/` delimiters.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it definitely isn't correct. Your regular expression checks whether the string starts with a backslash.

Comment: @Stephan dunno what OP wants.M waiting on him to clarify.But by what he has said..it seems he messed up with delimiters

Answer (score 0):

This is what you probably need:
`^[^/\\#?]{0,1024}$`

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: @vks your regex and op's are same, No improvent.

Comment: i think he mean `^[^\\]+$`

Answer (score 0):

There's insufficient information in the question to determine exactly what 'disallow the backslash' means, but if it is a simple matter of deleting a backslash wherever it occurs:

```js
var string = document.getElementById('input').innerHTML;
var output = string.replace(/\\/g, '');
alert(output);
```

```html
<div id = "input">\blah\blah\blah\</div>
```